# MVC-5: How to make a Foreign Key Column Disabled only while EditingViews

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

**INTENTION:**

Basically, I want to make specific columns non-editable using `Data-Annotations` In my model class generated through `Entity Framework-6.1.3`, I have already tried:

```
//model class
[ReadOnly(true)]
public int DepID { get; set; }
```

The above column named as `DepID` is a `Foreign-key` in this model class.

**PROBLEM:**

I don't know what's wrong with this. The field value is not being displayed as `readonly`

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Updated Answer @Carlo . Please inform me if there any other way to stop all foreign-keys to be editable in this format

Comment: Please clarify your question and rewrite your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really necessary to show the DepID? I recommend you to pass the DepID to your view as `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DepID)` inside your form. This way, when you send the data back to the server, the property still there.

Comment: Can you tell me too display the value in a label? @PedroBenevides

Comment: @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.DepID)

Comment: Thanks! please one more thing: How to display Yes/No Instead of True/False. @PedroBenevides

Comment: Which HTML element you'll use ?

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepCompleted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly="readonly" } })

Comment: model => model.DepPercentCompleted == 0 ? "No" : "Yes" . I have tried this, but it gives an Exception on RunTime @PedroBenevides

Comment: You can use a dropdown list, and set the Text property to yes or no. Or you can make your own HtmlHelper, if this component is necessary in other views. Or you could use a radio button, if it is to user choose a option. Here is the radio button example: http://doubleloop.net/blog/2015/02/06/nullable-bool-and-radiobuttons-in-asp-dot-net-mvc/

Comment: It is a business rule, so you should pass the information to your view, already computed, so in the Layer you make your ViewModel, you must verify this. And in your view model this property could be a Label.